# Spring data Hadoop, Hbase Rest API, HBase Java Client : which one would be the best to implement to handle communication between Android and HBase

Tags: android, spring, rest, hbase, spring-data-hadoop

Does anybody know what is the best method to communicate between HBase database and Android?

Basically I want to do following from my Android app to HBase table:

```
i.   Insert data into it.
ii.  Query table and get data.
iii. Update table.
```

I had done some research of my own.

1. **HBase Rest API**

   I found the functionality of the this api very limited. 
   I want to access multiple rows from a table. 
   This api only allows a single row to be selected.
   Also, perhaps no query support and less documentation is surely not making me use this api.
   And I dont want to expose DB directly.
2. **Spring data Hadoop**

   Frankly, I am not familiar with Spring. I read that it supports HBaseTemplate.
   Does anybody had used this with HBase and exposed it as a web api.
3. **HBase JAVA Client api**

   I believe **Spring data Hadoop** is more flexible than this.

So I believe 2. is the way to go.

Does anybody had tried something different, more cool and simpler.

**EDIT:**

I have solved my problem. I created a RESTFUL web Service with Spring-data-Hadoop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a restful service with Spring data Hadoop. This solved the problem.